# How to connect Parent and child list with JavaScript? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have a parent list called `Empribbon` and a child list called `Childribbon`. In my `Empribbon` list I have 3 Columns: `Title`, `Name`, `Age`, `Address` and `Phone No`.

[image]

In my `Childribbon` I have 3 other Columns: `Title`, `Employee(this is a lookup field, connected to Empribbon list to "Name" Column)` and `Skills`.

[image]

In my `Empribbon` I have also created a custom ribbon action on my `EditForm` named `newtochild`  which opens the new form for my `Childlist`

Now If I edit the first row In my parentlist which name is `Nderon Hiseni` and If I click on my custum action `newtochild` it opens the Default new form of my list, and all I want is that `Nderon Hisni` should be selected and disable for editing in my list.

How Can I do this. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use one list?

Comment: because I need to make it with childs

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I dare to say that your approach is weird. Why would you have "Title" property in both lists? Why couldn't you have "Skills" in the "Empribbon" List?

Comment: those are just sample lists, in reality I have 2 lists with more than 100 columns and this is the main reason why I need to make it in this way

Comment: pass list id and item id from the custom action as query str parameters, then have a JS in the newtochild new form which will get the query str parameters and assign the value to the required field.